# R plot function removes hours in x axis

Tags: r, datetime, plot, axis

I want to show the the following dataframe in a simple plot in R:

```
> df
  value            dateTime
1 -0.8 2018-04-02 06:00:00
2 -0.7 2018-04-02 06:01:00
3 -0.6 2018-04-02 06:02:00
4 -0.7 2018-04-02 06:03:00
5 -0.5 2018-04-02 06:04:00
6 -0.9 2018-04-02 06:05:00

> plot(df$dateTime, df$value, type = "o", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Value", cex.axis = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.5, ylim=c(-1,1))
```

The result is:
[image]

As you can see, the plot just shows the minutes and seconds in the x axis. However, I would like to have hours and minute in the x axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off adding the x-axis independently. Disable it in `plot()` by setting `xaxt="n"`. Then we can add it again using `axis.POSIXct()`, which has the argument `format` which lets us specify how date and time should be represented. Take a look at `?strptime` for how to specify this format.

```
df <- structure(list(value=c(-0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.7, -0.5, -0.9),
  dateTime=structure(c(1522641600, 1522641660, 1522641720,
  1522641780, 1522641840, 1522641900), class=c("POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"), tzone="")), class="data.frame", row.names=c(NA,
  -6L))

plot(df[,2:1], ylim=c(-1, 1), xaxt="n", type="o")
axis.POSIXct(1, df$dateTime, format="%H:%M")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my previous answer was confusing. I think `ggplot2` will do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
df<-tibble(
  value = c(-0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.7, -0.5, -0.9), 
  dateTime = ymd_hms(
     "2018-04-02 06:00:00", "2018-04-02 06:01:00",
     "2018-04-02 06:02:00", "2018-04-02 06:03:00",
     "2018-04-02 06:04:00", "2018-04-02 06:05:00") )

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dateTime,  y = value)) + 
  geom_line() + scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 min"), 
               labels = date_format("%H:%M"))
```

Comment: Have you added `library(scales)`?